# How do you get gulp-exec to print to stdout when a command fails?

Tags: gulp

I'm using the following code to kick off a process from gulp running on Windows 8:

```
gulp.src('test.bat')
  .pipe($.exec('test.bat <%= file.path %>'))
  .pipe($.exec.reporter());
```

The batch file in the current folder contains the following:

```
@echo off

echo This is a test to stdout
echo The script was passed %*

exit 0
```

The output is as follows:

```
[11:27:40] This is a test to stdout
The script was passed C:\temp\test.bat
```

If the batch file returns -1, the output is as follows:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "test.bat C:\temp\test.bat"

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

How do I get gulp.exec() to firstly print the standard output from the script and secondly fail more gracefully?  the error coming from events.js isn't something I should expect to see, but rather some graceful error message concerning the failure of the command.  According to the docs, all the default options should already be set up to output stdout and stderr, so not sure what I might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

`gulp-exec` assumes that the command will return 0 for success and non-0 for failure, and that failure means you want the build to fail.  (It should still dump `stdout` and `stderr` to the console before it crashes the build though.)  If those assumptions don't hold true, you're likely better avoiding gulp-exec and doing this instead:

```
var through2 = require('through2');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('sometask', function() {
    return gulp.src('**/*.js')
        .pipe(through2.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
            var that = this;
            exec('test.bat some args here', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                // take appropriate action then
                that.push(file);
                cb(null);
            });
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: I do want the build to fail on a non-zero return value, but as detailed above it isn't printing the standard output and it's showing internal errors of the gulp.exe() command (i.e. the events error).

Comment: Yeah, `through2` isn't very good at surfacing errors.  That gets better in gulp 4.  In the mean time, writing your own function to surface errors and handle conditions is a pretty sweet solution.  Alternatively, there's some cool techniques with `.pipe(...).on('error', function (err) {...`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could fix with the following approach:

```
gulp.src('test.bat')
    .pipe($.exec('test.bat <%= file.path %>', function cb(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout); // outputs the normal messages
        console.log(stderr); // outputs the error messages
        return 0; // makes gulp continue even if the command failed
    }))
    .pipe($.exec.reporter());
```

The tricky part here is that the `exec` provides a callback function (`$.exec(command, callback)`), where we can log the outputs and bypass the command's return by simply returning `0`!